# Nodejs Nginx serve static files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have nodejs running on port 5000. And I have another app which runs on port 8000 as main app.
First one is php app, which is main. And nodeApp as second app.

So, here is my nginx sites-available/default file:

```
 listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/analytics_dashboard/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /nodeApp/ {
       root /root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/static;
       rewrite ^/nodeApp/(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /static {
            root /root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/static;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

So, when I'm going to / main page, I can access php app.

When I come to /nodeApp/ I see html page of my nodeApp. But there is 403 error.
 Like this `http://<my-server>/static/js/...` 403 Forbidden error. 

And here is nginx error log:

```
"GET /static/js/app.b790250b5af64ad68f13.js HTTP/1.1" 403 192 "http://<my-server>/marser/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Here what I have in nginx error log:

```
/root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/static/js/app.b790250b5af64ad68f13.js" failed (13: Permission denied), request: "GET /static/js/app.b790250b5af64ad68f13.js HTTP/1.1"
```

But, I've set permissions with `chmod 777` for all files in static directory.

I've also tried rewriting nginx sites-available/default file to change

```
location /static {
        alias /root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/static;
}
```

But still haven't succeed.
So, my question is:

How to serve nodejs app static files for second application in nginx?

P.S.
I've already read this articles: [first](https://hashnode.com/post/how-to-make-nginx-read-static-files-directory-when-proxy-passing-cj1yw4esm007mzz53dj40vle2), [second](https://geekflare.com/nginx-static-files-node-js/), [third](https://gist.github.com/jhjguxin/6208474),[fourth](https://www.sitepoint.com/configuring-nginx-ssl-node-js/),[fifth](https://www.nginx.com/blog/5-performance-tips-for-node-js-applications/).

Comment: Can you run in debug mode?

Comment: @ColeTierney what exactly in debug mode?

Comment: If your nginx was compiled with the option --with-debug, then you can append space debug to your error log path to get lots of verbose diagnostics.

Comment: Run `nginx -V` to see if --with-debug is in the configure arguments. If so, enabling debug mode is a good way to trace how nginx is handling a request.

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, you might try turning on autoindex and see if your error message changes. If for some reason your request is finding a directory instead of a file, you would see a 403 error if autoindex is off. Add the following near the top of your server stanza:

```
autoindex on;
```

If nginx was configured with `--with-debug` (nginx -V to check), try enabling debug mode by adding 'debug' to the end of your error log:

```
error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log debug;
```

This will trace how nginx is handling a request.

Comment: Nope, still same result. Problem is, server try to find file like this from nginx error log. `/root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/js/app.b790250b5af64ad68f13.js`. But there is no file here. They exist in `/root/nodeApp/source/front/dist/static/...` folder.